# UIWebview in a modal view is being shown in portrait in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview, modalviewcontroller

I browsed through most of the questions and tried almost everything. But bad part is that the issue is still there.

I have a `UIVIew` which is always launched in landscape mode and I am presenting a second view (`detailView`) as a full screen modal view.

The `detailview` has a `UIwebview` on top of it.

When I present the `detailView` as a modal view, the webview is being shown in portrait mode.

I am returning "`YES`" in `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and also have set `autoresize` , `autoresizingMask` and `scalePageToFit` properties.

When I rotate the device, and when the `detailView` is in front, the webview arranges to landscape properly.

The issue is only when I present the `modalView` for the first time.

Rotating the device is adjusting the layout properly.

Comment: And I have also tried setting the status bar in modal view's viewWillAppear., i.e, [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: self.interfaceOrientation]... Even this doesnt work

Comment: :try this - crate one custom viewController(say - FirstViewController) of class UIViewController. in this VC, support both orientations (Port and Land). Then create SecondViewController which will be subclass of FirstViewController, obviously in this u will create UIView with landscape mode and do same further as u did.

Comment: The termins `landscape` or `portrait` mode are related to `UIViewController` but not to `UIView`. So could you clarify what do you mean under portrait mode of `UIWebView`. Which method do you use to show `UIWebView` on top of `detailview`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK. First of all, the question I had posted was not clear. My question was that, when I load a webview, in portrait, it was loading  the webview elements in landscape mode(CSS), and was getting loaded as portrait mode(CSS) in landscape orientation.

Turns out that I was not applying the correct CSS style.

The fix I did was:
In ViewDidLoad and willAnimateRotation method, I am posting a notification to my javascript to update the style based on orientation :)

Comment: could you please show the code for this - I'm having the same problems but have no clue when it comes to javascript

Comment: @iOSProgrammingIsFun Can you please elaborate on your problem? I did this thing sometime back. I need to search for my code.

Comment: Ok, I have a viewcontroller A the presents view controller B modally, and in full screen style. Inside VC B is a full screen uiwebview. That webview is used to show a specific website - say Wikipedia. If the app is run in portrait, then the web page is formatted to be portrait and is scaled to fit the web view - even though scalestofit is un ticked in interface builder. I'd the same page was opened in mobile safari the width of the page exceeds the width of the screen and is more readable, it can also be zoomed, where as the webview in VC B cannot. Also if VC B is rotated the page is messed up

Comment: Such that it is partially scrolled off the top of the physical screen and can't be scrolled down. There is no additional formatting changes applied in code for different orientations. Also the web page still only fits the width of the physical screen and is not wider (like it is in mobile safari).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware ModalViews on the iPhone do not support Landscape View. The case may be different for iPhone 5.

But it sounds like you are setting the ModalView not the WebView to landscape, I'd suggest a different approach to handling this.

For Example you could animate the DetailView in like a ModalView so it starts in the correct orientation

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your app on iOS 6 you will need the following code in the modal view controller to support the landscape orientation:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Also, make sure you are testing on the actual device as opposed to the simulator because auto-rotation behaves differently on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

That will do the trick:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
webView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform,-M_PI/2);
```